# Adjusting UICollectionView scroll speed/sensitivity

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

I'm trying to slow down the scroll in a UICollectionView. Everything works great and the distance between the cells is fine, but it just moves too fast.

How can I adjust the sensitivity or speed of the scroll?

[Edit] I forgot to mentioned that I already tried:

```
self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
```

and

```
self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
```

With no significant change in speed...

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, so you can adjust the `decelerationRate` in your collection view controller's `viewDidLoad`, like so:

Objective-C:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast;
};
```

Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
}
```

Comment: Already tried UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast and UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal with no significant change. Are there other properties I can use?

Comment: I'm not aware of any. I've just tested it in one of my own projects, and setting the `decelerationRate` of a `UICollectionView` to `UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast` slows down scrolling _significantly_. Are you sure your reference to your collectionView is right? If you're creating your objects in IB, have you checked your outlets are setup correctly?

Comment: Yep all connected how it's supposed to. Do you think the layout may have something to do with it?

Comment: It's possible I suppose, though not aware of anything in UICollectionViewLayout that messes with deceleration rates. There's `targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:withScrollingVelocity:`, but that just returns the point at which to stop scrolling. Are you using a custom (flow) layout? If so, can you post the code?

Comment: I've tried playing around with the `UIScrollView.decelerationRate` but the range it allows is `0.990000` to `0.998000`, which isn't much adjustment.

Comment: Manually adjusting `decelerationRate` doesn't change it's value at all.

Comment: @followben BOOM! You saved my life :) i didn't know about that one! cheers

Comment: It improves scrolling speed of collection view cell.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking how to do it in Swift

```
 self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast
```

Swift 5:

```
 self.collectionView.decelerationRate = UIScrollView.DecelerationRate.fast
```

Comment: With Swift there should be a more succinct way to express this.

Answer (score 0):

For those not using a `UICollectionViewController`, I was searching high and low for a way to make this work. Turns out if you subclass `UICollectionView` itself, and set `self.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateFast` in the ever required `init(coder aDecoder:)` method, you're good to go.

Speculation as to the cause of this is that UICollectionView doesn't like adjusting the deceleration rate after the layout has been created. I can't be certain, and I've wasted more than enough time on this. Just thought I'd post answer though.

> **SDK:** iOS 9+
>   **Xcode:** 8.3.2
>   **Swift:** 3.1